# Any reason to avoid acos in Python?

Tags: python, fortran, precision, trigonometry, fortran77

I'm rewriting an old Fortran 77 program in Python. Scattered around the code, there are a lot of statements like these:

```
HPI=1.570791
V=HPI-DASIN(COS_V)
SIN_V=DSQRT(1.D0-COS_V**2)
```

Two different trigonometric formulas (the [relationship between asin and acos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_among_the_inverse_trigonometric_functions) and the [pythagorean trigonometric identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity)) are used there. The purpose seems to be to avoid using acos at all cost, presumably to maintain precision or perhaps for speed.

In Python all my floats have double precision. I would find the code much more readable if I could just use `math.acos`:

```
v = math.acos(cos_v)
sin_v = math.sin(v)
```

Is there any reasons not to do this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say your floats have double precision? Are you using standard Python floats? I believe standard Python floats are doubles. See here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html. Python math functions return floats. So would be fine in that case. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html

Comment: "Almost all machines today (November 2000) use IEEE-754 floating point arithmetic, and almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE-754 “double precision”. 754 doubles contain 53 bits of precision"  – https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: I could see an argument for calculating `sin_v` with `math.sqrt(1 - cos_v**2)`, but if you need the value of `v` itself, you have to use a reverse trigonometric function anyway. I can't see why the Fortran code would prefer to use asin insread of acos. Unless acos hadn't been invented. Or they wanted to make sure the value for `v` they got was in some particular range.

Comment: @Sarcoma Yes, I am using "standard" Python, nothing special or fancy. Not sure about the correct terminology here, so I might be expressing it wrong.

Comment: I can't speak for the equations, but floats are floats, so you'd be fine to use the math functions. Just need to take care, as ever, with rounding issues.

Comment: The formula above does not match the identity given in your first link - the correct expression for the angle `V` is `HPI-DASIN(COS_V)` (without `/2`). Could it have been used for a different purpose (or just bad variable naming)? Show a more complete snippet of where this is being applied.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog My apologies, it was me who pasted different part of the code together to get a good example. I have corrected the question.

Comment: It's almost certainly very old code originally for some long defunct architecture upon which sqrt was faster than acos. Nowadays write the code in the obvious way.

Comment: @IanBush It is indeed very old. I just found a reference in one of the comments that part of the code had been *upgraded* to Fortran 77.